# How to create new windows AMI with packer

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, packer

I have an EC2 running Windows with 2 volumes, one for OS and one for DB and application.
I've tried to search in Packer docs for creating new updated image but all I've found is that I need to provide existing AMI ID, which currently I don't have.
How can I use packer to create an update image of the running instance?

Comment: Create an AMI from your running instance. Then use that AMI ID. I recommend selecting the reboot option when creating the AMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Packer documentation:

> **What is Packer?**
>
> Packer is an open source tool for creating identical machine images for multiple platforms from a single source configuration. [Ref](https://www.packer.io/intro/index.html#what-is-packer-)

*Packer can't create an image from a running instance* and that is not the purpose of Packer, since that would not be repeatable.

Instead just follow the AWS documentation for [Creating a Windows AMI from a Running Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Creating_EBSbacked_WinAMI.html#how-to-create-windows-ebs-ami).